# MAUI and iOS: provisioning files

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ios-simulator, maui

I'm creating a `NET8` `MAUI` application and I like to test it, at least, in a `iOS` simulator. After connecting my macOS, I try to run the app in a simulator (iPhone 15) but I get this error

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for LanguageInUse on iOS.

So, I read the Microsoft documentation about [Automatic Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows).

In the *Properties* of the project in the *iOS* section, I find the configuration but no *Team* is selected because I don't have one.

[image]

In the *Manage Account*, I have to insert my Apple account and get a key from the Apple Developer website.

[image]

The get this key I have to pay Apple and because I'm just playing around, I don't want to pay Apple for a developer account. At least not yet.

Is it possible to test my `MAUI` application in an Apple Simulator without paying Apple for a developer account? Can I skip the provisioning certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to test my MAUI application in an Apple Simulator
> without paying Apple for a developer account? Can I skip the
> provisioning certificate?

If you want to test in an Apple Simulator, using automatic provisioning is recommended so that additional iOS devices can be easily configured for deployment.

For how to use automatic provisioning, you can select `Automatic Provisioning` and then click the `Configure Automatic Provisioning` hyperlink:

[image]

Then the `Configure Automatic Provisioning` dialog will appear.

[image]

Visual Studio will complete the automatic provisioning process. Then, click the `Ok` button to dismiss the `Configure Automatic Provisioning` dialog.

**Note:**

For more information, please check the official document: [Deploy an iOS app using hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0),especially steps `14` and `15`.